# Using QGIS -- when I reopen the project, information I've previous converted to INT or DEC is STRING again

Tags: qgis

I'm building maps to analyze public voter data.

The precinct maps are shapefiles, to which I join voter data from CSV files. To get them to behave like numbers I use the field calculator to convert the voter data to INT or DEC depending on what I'm using it for. However, whenever I close & save the project, and reopen it later. All of the new fields I've converted to numbers convert back to text, and none of the calculations are working until I redo all the work I've already done.

Is there something that I'm obviously doing wrong?

Comment: https://anitagraser.com/2011/03/07/how-to-specify-data-types-of-csv-columns-for-use-in-qgis/ https://bnhr.xyz/2018/08/07/specifying-csv-data-types-using-a-csvt-file.html

Comment: Add CSV as a vector layer instead of a delimited text.